# Equivalent of document.getElementsByClassName

Tags: ocaml, js-of-ocaml

I can't find a js_of_ocaml equivalent of `document.getElementsByClassName`. What is the canonical way to do?

EDIT : I'm using js_of_ocaml v2.5.

Comment: To add to the 2 other answers, which are correct, a pull request on js_of_ocaml to add this method would be welcome. :)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem to exist.

The closest I can find to that is by using the `className` attribute of `DOM_html` elements ([docs](https://ocsigen.org/js_of_ocaml/2.5/api/Dom_html.element-c#METHODclassName)) and `DOM_svg` elements ([docs](https://ocsigen.org/js_of_ocaml/2.5/api/Dom_svg.stylable-c#METHODclassName)). You can then iterate through the collection and get the element you want.

This was taken from [method index](https://ocsigen.org/js_of_ocaml/2.5/api/index_methods) which I searched through.

The DOM document class however does have getElementById and getElementBy tag name as shown [here](https://ocsigen.org/js_of_ocaml/api/Dom.document-c).

`method getElementById : Js.js_string Js.t -> 'element Js.t Js.opt Js.meth`

`method getElementsByTagName : Js.js_string Js.t -> 'element nodeList Js.t Js.meth`

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function that will call it directly:

```
let getElementsByClassName (name : Js.js_string Js.t)
    : Dom_html.element Dom.nodeList Js.t =
  Js.Unsafe.meth_call
    Dom_html.document "getElementsByClassName" [|Js.Unsafe.inject name|]
```

The signature is based on the signature of `Dom.document##getElementsByTagName`. The type constraints are necessary for type-safe usage.

You can use it like this:

```
getElementsByClassName (Js.string "control")
```

You may want to change the interface so it takes an OCaml string, in the style of the `Dom_html.getElementById`. Then, maybe you should also make it return an OCaml list.

Answer (score 1):

I needed that function too some weeks ago, so I made a PR https://github.com/ocsigen/js_of_ocaml/pull/312

Comment: Ok thanks, I thought there was some sort of magic mechanism already there. :)